# Multiple bars for each x axis value using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to have 2 bars for each time in the bar chart. 
X axis has to be time and y axis has to be count. 
For each time I am trying to plot 2 bars for each id.

```
  Id    Time Count
  585   10  9
  585   11  34
  585   12  96
  193   10  147
  193   11  85
  193   12  1
```

Tried with the below code but could not get the desired results. Any help would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance !!

```
  y = df1['Id']
  z = df1['Count']

  ax = plt.subplot(111)
  ax.bar(y, z,width=0.2,color='b',align='center')
  ax.bar(y, z,width=0.2,color='g',align='center')
  ax.xaxis_date()

  plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`set_index` + `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['Time', 'Id']).Count.unstack().plot.bar()
```

[image]

This time with `Count` as the `ylabel`

```
ax = df.set_index(['Time', 'Id']).Count.unstack().plot.bar()
ax.set_ylabel('Count')
```

[image]